# How can i touch multiple things at a time and not only one in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm building a web that acts like a controller and then sends the data through websocket, i encounter a problem and after quick search on google doesn't help me. The problem is when i put my finger on the web it only register one finger at a time, so when i moving the joystick and then pressing the other button, the joystick will not be working until i release the new finger.

What i'm trying to ask is how can i touch multiple things at a time and not only one at a time

Here is the screenshot and the code

```js
var canvas, ctx;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  resize();

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', Draw);

  document.addEventListener('touchstart', startDrawing);
  document.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
  document.addEventListener('touchcancel', stopDrawing);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', Draw);
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

  document.getElementById("x_coordinate").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("y_coordinate").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("speed").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("angle").innerText = 0;
});




var width, height, radius, x_orig, y_orig;

function resize() {
  width = 250;
  radius = 50;
  height = 250;
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  background();
  joystick(width / 2, height / 3);
}

function background() {
  x_orig = width / 2;
  y_orig = height / 3;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x_orig, y_orig, radius + 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ECE5E5';
  ctx.fill();
}

function joystick(width, height) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(width, height, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#F08080';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#F6ABAB';
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.stroke();
}

let coord = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let paint = false;

function getPosition(event) {
  var mouse_x = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
  var mouse_y = event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY;
  coord.x = mouse_x - canvas.offsetLeft;
  coord.y = mouse_y - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function is_it_in_the_circle() {
  var current_radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coord.x - x_orig, 2) + Math.pow(coord.y - y_orig, 2));
  if (radius >= current_radius) return true
  else return false
}


function startDrawing(event) {
  paint = true;
  getPosition(event);
  if (is_it_in_the_circle()) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    background();
    joystick(coord.x, coord.y);
    Draw();
  }
}


function stopDrawing() {
  paint = false;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  background();
  joystick(width / 2, height / 3);
  document.getElementById("x_coordinate").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("y_coordinate").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("speed").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("angle").innerText = 0;

}

function Draw(event) {

  if (paint) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    background();
    var angle_in_degrees, x, y, speed;
    var angle = Math.atan2((coord.y - y_orig), (coord.x - x_orig));

    if (Math.sign(angle) == -1) {
      angle_in_degrees = Math.round(-angle * 180 / Math.PI);
    } else {
      angle_in_degrees = Math.round(360 - angle * 180 / Math.PI);
    }


    if (is_it_in_the_circle()) {
      joystick(coord.x, coord.y);
      x = coord.x;
      y = coord.y;
    } else {
      x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + x_orig;
      y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + y_orig;
      joystick(x, y);
    }


    getPosition(event);

    var speed = Math.round(100 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x_orig, 2) + Math.pow(y - y_orig, 2)) / radius);

    var x_relative = Math.round(x - x_orig);
    var y_relative = Math.round(y - y_orig);


    document.getElementById("x_coordinate").innerText = x_relative;
    document.getElementById("y_coordinate").innerText = y_relative;
    document.getElementById("speed").innerText = speed;
    document.getElementById("angle").innerText = angle_in_degrees;

    //send( x_relative,y_relative,speed,angle_in_degrees);
    //send(angle_in_degrees, speed, x_relative, y_relative);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-buttons,
.bot-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bot-buttons {
  height: 100%;
}

.top-buttons>.left,
.top-buttons>.right {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bot-buttons>.left {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
}

.bot-buttons>.right {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto 50px auto auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.xb,
.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.a,
.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.y {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.xb {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.xb>.x,
.bot-buttons>.right>.xyab>.xb>.b {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#lt {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(assets/360_LT.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
}

#lb {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(assets/360_LB.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#rt {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(assets/360_RT.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#rb {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(assets/360_RB.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#x {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(assets/360_X.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  margin: auto 20px auto auto;
}

#y {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(assets/360_Y.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

#a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(assets/360_A.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

#b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(assets/360_B.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  margin: auto auto auto 20px;
}

button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"] {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>XBOX 360 Virtual</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden;position: fixed;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-buttons">
      <div class="left">
        <button id="lt"></button>
        <button id="lb"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <button id="rb"></button>
        <button id="rt"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot-buttons">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="lsb">
          <p style="text-align: center;">
            X: <span id="x_coordinate"> </span> Y: <span id="y_coordinate"> </span> Speed: <span id="speed"> </span> % Angle: <span id="angle"> </span>
          </p>
          <canvas id="canvas" name="game"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="xyab">
          <div class="y">
            <button id="y"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="xb">
            <div class="x">
              <button id="x"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="b">
              <button id="b"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="a">
            <button id="a"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the image:

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Start by reading up on multi-touch here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Multi-touch_interaction

Comment: Someone please explain why you are downvoting this question! This is a well written question with a clear, singular objective including source code.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah, i'm wondering why too ? Is it because am a newbie here and asking some stupid question ?

Comment: Your question meets all the community guidelines and is fine. Some people will see an image at the top and immediately downvote for that. You should move your question (the last sentence) to the very top of the post - that will help others understand your intent.

Comment: Also, move the image so that it is after the code.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm new to this kind of thing, struggling to understand that, can you explain why my code isn't working ? is it the JS only registering one touch or what ?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation in the link I sent. It should be clear that you have not addressed the issue with event handlers sufficiently after you read the related docs.

Comment: @RandyCasburn am i doing it wrong because i set the "ontouchstart" to the entire document on not the element ?

Comment: I can't read the docs for you, but you can search that page for this string: `ev.targetTouches.length == 2` - This is **the** test for multiple touches that **does not show up in your code**. Good luck to you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i've read the entire document, and still doesn't know what to do.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What i get from the document is, i need to init the touch handler for each element, handling pitch/zoom motion, touch start, touch end and etc. And i don't know how to apply it to my code

Comment: @RandyCasburn After bunch of trial and error, i'm making a progress, it now can handle multiple touch, but it's not done yet cause i can't touch the other buttons